# Clock-like rotation with animation keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I've painted 8 dots in a circle. I want to rotate the circle, but abruptly like a clock hand, not smoothly. For every 12.5% of the time it takes to do the full rotation, I want to increase the rotation angle by 45 degrees.

I defined my animation like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes clock { 

  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  12.4% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  12.5%{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  24.9% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  25%{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  ...
```

My crude attempt to eliminate intervening keyframes by specifying percentages very close together isn't quite passing muster. I get occasional choppiness, which I'm guessing is due to some rounding issue.

Note, I have other ways to achieve the animation I am after, I am specifically asking about if we can apply abrupt effects in CSS keyframe animations.

ref: http://codepen.io/chardie/pen/embLrP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function) for the animation to be `steps(1)` instead of `linear`. That prevents the smooth transition between the states that you want to avoid:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raoQGm

```css
#loading{
    -webkit-animation: 3s clock infinite steps(1);
}
@-webkit-keyframes clock {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    12.5%{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    25%{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    ...
}
```